# Exchange 2010 Mailbox forwarding

Tags: exchange-2010

I've got Exchange 2010 and would like to create an email address (lets say testemail@email.com) and send it to a real email address (lets say user@email.com).  How do I go about doing this so that all the email sent to 'testemail@email.com' goes to 'user@email.com' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Create a Mailcontact `testemail@email.com` (the new email address)
Use Transport rules to redirect it to a existing or new mailbox of your choice
Mail contacts :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998858.aspx
http://www.ntweekly.com/?p=1045

Transport Rules : `http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995961.aspx`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want internal address@domain1.com to go to an external address@domain2.com then a Mail Contact is all you need.

If you want internal address1@domain1.com to to internal address2.domain1.com then you only need to go to the address2@domain1.com mailbox and add the other address as a secondary SMTP address.  The user will then receive mail to *both* addresses in their mailbox.

Comment: Based on the description, this would be the best route. Really we're adding an email alias to an existing user. bob@example.com might receive email sent to webmaster@example.com.

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2007 you would create a `Mail Contact` in the `Recpient Configuration`.

A mail contact is described as

> A mail-enabled Active Directory contact that contains information about people or organizations that exist outside an Exchange organization. Each mail contact has an external e-mail address. All messages sent to the mail contact are routed to this external e-mail address.

So I think this should be fitting your needs since you seem to look for a 1:1 relationship between testuser@email.com and user@email.com and don't want e-mails to be distributed to multiple users.

(*maybe someone with experience in Exchange2010 should verify this*)